# SQP method with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Am trying to write the SQP method with Python and am having so much difficulties.

Am using a book : Jorge Nocedal and Stephen J. Wright. Numerical optimization. (open acces)

this book says that we have to solve this problem:

[image: page 553]

I  calculated the right matrix, let us call it H as well as the left matrix let's call this one G, in order to find pk and lambda k+1.

How can I solve this ?

This is what I tryed :

```
H=[[[[1,0],[0,1]],[[-2],[0]]],
   [[2,0],0]
   ]
G=[[[-1],[-1]],
   0
   ]
H=np.array(H)
G=np.array(G)
np.linalg.solve(H,G)
```

Or

```
np.linalg.lstsq(H,G)
```

but both gave me some error :

```
TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting
was found for ufunc solve1
```

and

```
setting an array element with a sequence.
```

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: The way you define your matrices is the problem. `H` is supposed to be a list of row lists before you convert it into a numpy array. Same goes for `G`

Comment: Thank you for your answer @cel , but how can I write it like this knowing that it is a matrix made of matrix?

Comment: Can you write out in latex what you want `H` and `G` to look like? I'm struggling to see any structure in your lists of lists

Comment: Much better, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numpy doesn't understand matrices of matrices - you need to flatten these into a single matrix, which you can do as:

```
H = np.array([
    [1, 0, -2]
    [0, 1,  0],
    [2, 0,  0],
])

G = np.array([
    [-1],
    [-1],
    [0]
])

np.linalg.solve(H,G)
```

If you want to assemble these from their parts, you can do

```
Ak         = np.array([[2, 0]])
laplace_Lk = np.eye(2)
grad_fk    = np.array([[1, 1]]).T
ck         = 0

H = np.r_[
    np.c_[laplace_Lk, -Ak.T],
    np.c_[        Ak,     0]
]
G = np.c_[-grad_fk, -ck]
```

In the upcoming `1.13`, you could also write this as:

```
H = np.block([
   [laplace_Lk, -Ak.T],
   [        Ak,     0]
]
G = np.block([
    [-grad_fk ],
    [-ck      ]
])
```

Comment: With `Ak` unchanged? The matrix multiply wouldn't make sense

Comment: OK thank you !! and you mean np.bmat instead of np.block ?

Comment: `np.block` is new in numpy 1.13. In 2d, `np.block(...)` is the same as `np.bmat(...).A`